# Exception in PDO Firebird prepare of query in Magento Integration

Tags: php, magento, pdo, prepared-statement, firebird

I'm working on project which is integrated with client's ERP* directly through php firebird pdo extension to get information as brands, categories, products, product prices and etc.

Database is not on the server where script runs. Connection to database works over a VPN connection if this matters.

First of all script asks Firebird for few queries in one of the system tables called `SYS$ACTION_DS`, Firebird returns this query:

```
execute block (
    MARK_AS_PROCESSED DM_BOOL = :MARK_AS_PROCESSED,
    EXTENAL_SYSTEM_ID DM_123 = :EXTENAL_SYSTEM_ID)
returns (
    ID bigint,
    BRAND_NAME$1 DM_STR30,
    BRAND_NAME$2 DM_STR30,
    BRAND_PARENT_REF bigint,
    OP varchar(1))
as
DECLARE VARIABLE SL_ID BIGINT;
begin
  FOR SELECT SL.ID, SL.OPERATION, SL.TABLE_ID_REF, N.BRAND_NAME$1, N.BRAND_NAME$2, N.BRAND_PARENT_REF
      FROM  SYS$EXT_LOG SL
      LEFT JOIN NOM$BRANDS N ON (SL.TABLE_ID_REF = N.ID)
      WHERE (SL.PROCESSED = 0) AND (SL.EXTERNAL_SYSTEM_ID = :EXTENAL_SYSTEM_ID) AND (SL.TABLE_NAME = 'NOM$BRANDS')
      ORDER BY SL.ID
      INTO :SL_ID, :OP, :ID, :BRAND_NAME$1, :BRAND_NAME$2, :BRAND_PARENT_REF
  do begin
    suspend;
    if (MARK_AS_PROCESSED = 1) then
      update SYS$EXT_LOG SL set SL.PROCESSED = 1, SL.PROCESSED_ON = current_timestamp where SL.ID = :SL_ID;
  end
end
```

After that script tries to prepare PDO Statement but prepare throws an exception: `Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 18, column 12 ?`

I can't find why I've got this error but everything works fine on live server but not on my machine. I've tried few php versions (5.6, 7.0, 7.1) on my machine and nothing works, on live server php version is 5.5 but I can't find any change between 5.5 and 5.6 related with PDO or Firebird PDO.

**Additional information**:
Firebird Server Version: 2.5.5.26

Comment: The table `SYS$ACTION_DS` is not a system table, as all Firebird system tables start either with `RDB$` or `MON$`.

Comment: Version 2.5.5.26 does not exist, it is either just 2.5.5 or 2.5.5.26952_0 if you want to provide exact build, and it is not the latest 2.5.x version. Several security bugs (and other bugs) have been fixed since 2.5.5.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel - I'm not familiar with Firebird, this is my first try with it. About version - this is what I get when I ask for server version through pdo->getServerVersion() (Method is available through Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract)

Comment: I've checked and the exact version: 2.5.5.26952

Comment: For version see `RDB$GET_CONTEXT()` at http://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html

Answer (score 2):

Currently PDO Firebird driver do a simple primitive replacement of named parameters, by replacing :param with ?, as FB does not support named parameters. More info in PDO FB [driver source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a0ed09f92b66a86de4cbc2bd17e245f007626133/ext/pdo_firebird/firebird_driver.c#L382)

Unfortunately, this does not work for "execute block" statements. I hope, and do some efforts to have this fixed in the future. This was discussed in FB forum, to add named parameters support and also in PHP dev forums and [tracker](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64937) to improve the driver.

For now, as an workaround you may use a stored procedure.

Comment: Then how it works with PHP 5.5.18 but not with 5.6.32 and etc ?

Comment: @T0m3kk, this _never_ worked in PDO Firebird. A lot of fixes in PDO FB was applied just in PHP7, so I don't recommend to use PDO FB in PHP5.x. Maybe it is treated differently in ibase_ extension, as it does not support named parameters.

Comment: I don't know why - but it works on 5.5 as I said on client's live server. This was our goal - to upgrade to project to php 7.1 and use it's performance but if we can't run this synchronization migration to 7.1 will be pointless :)

Also may be the fix is in Zend framework PDO class but I don't know for the moment and I'm still debugging it.

Comment: @T0m3kk, if I said it never worked, then this means it *never* worked. I know pretty good PDO FB internals. This bug dates from 2013 (PHP5.4): https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=64937 Double check your scenarios on existing deployment.

Comment: As I said - it work on client's server if you want I can record you a video with additional code information :)

Comment: OK, make a video by executing this block in a simple PHP script: https://gist.github.com/madorin/6c2bfbbf207504b4589b0faab7dfb78c

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Firebird doesn't have named parameter outside PSQL blocks, and PDO Firebird seems to provide a translation to simulate support for this.

For example, raw execution of

```
execute block (
    MARK_AS_PROCESSED DM_BOOL = :MARK_AS_PROCESSED,
    EXTENAL_SYSTEM_ID DM_123 = :EXTENAL_SYSTEM_ID)
.. etc..
```

Would raise

```
SQL Message : -104
Invalid token

Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 2, column 33
:
```

The PDO Firebird library will replace the parameter names with a `?`, and given the error, and named parameter replacement, what gets executed is something like:

```
execute block (
    MARK_AS_PROCESSED DM_BOOL = ?,
    EXTENAL_SYSTEM_ID DM_123 = ?)
returns (
    ID bigint,
    BRAND_NAME$1 DM_STR30,
    BRAND_NAME$2 DM_STR30,
    BRAND_PARENT_REF bigint,
    OP varchar(1))
as
DECLARE VARIABLE SL_ID BIGINT;
begin
  FOR SELECT SL.ID, SL.OPERATION, SL.TABLE_ID_REF, N.BRAND_NAME$1, N.BRAND_NAME$2, N.BRAND_PARENT_REF
      FROM  SYS$EXT_LOG SL
      LEFT JOIN NOM$BRANDS N ON (SL.TABLE_ID_REF = N.ID)
      WHERE (SL.PROCESSED = 0) AND (SL.EXTERNAL_SYSTEM_ID = ?) AND (SL.TABLE_NAME = 'NOM$BRANDS')
      ORDER BY SL.ID
      INTO ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
  do begin
    suspend;
    if (MARK_AS_PROCESSED = 1) then
      update SYS$EXT_LOG SL set SL.PROCESSED = 1, SL.PROCESSED_ON = current_timestamp where SL.ID = ?;
  end
end
```

Note the `?` in the `into`-clause. This is what triggers the exception, because a `?` is not valid here.

I don't actually know PDO Firebird, but it looks like it will replace all occurrences of `:<variablename>` with a `?`. As PDO Firebird seems to do wholesale replacement of everything that looks like `:<variable>`, then you could try using positional parameters (and hope it doesn't still replace every `:<variable>` with a `?` as well),

```
execute block (
    MARK_AS_PROCESSED DM_BOOL = ?,
    EXTENAL_SYSTEM_ID DM_123 = ?)
.. etc..
```

or you will need to create an actual stored procedure (and not use PDO Firebird to create it), and execute that from PDO Firebird.

If this worked in early version of PHP, then you seem to have hit a regression, and I suggest you report a regression bug with the PDO project.

Comment: The problem mentioned in exception is on line 18, column 12 - right after "INTO" in query.

And then - how it works with PHP 5.5.18 but not with 5.6.32 and etc ?

Comment: @T0m3kk I don't use PHP and don't know PDO Firebird, I'm answering based on my knowledge of Firebird. You are right that I misjudged the location of the exception, and I'll revise my answer. In any case, part of the problem seems to be that **all** occurrences of `:<variablename>` are replaced with a `?` including those in the `into` clause. I suggest you file a bug with the PDO project.